LAMMPS structure rotation
I need to rotate half of the structure 180 degrees, I was able to do this operation but the rotation cannot be made symmetrical, do you have any ideas?
commands I used:
end result:


It looks like you just need to center the system before the rotation.  If you do this, it should line up correctly.
ASE may also be a good resource for this type of system manipulation if you dont need it in the middle of a LAAMPs run.
